# How to set indention to QImage in QLabel?

Tags: c++, qt

I have a `QImage` and wants to set it on a `Qlabel`.
For that I am using `QPixmap`. Something like this

```
QPixmap pixmap(QPixmap::fromImage(my_qimage));
mLabel->setIndent(42);
mLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);
```

Here I want to set the image after an indention of 42 pixels. But it is not working with Pixmap.
Although I tried the same with text like this

```
mLabel->setIndent(42);
mLabel->setText("image");
```

and it is working fine.

So my question is how can I set the image after an indentation of some pixels on a `QLabel`?
Any help will be appreciated. If there is an alternate way to achieve such behavior please suggest.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You probably are looking for `setMargin(int)` [property](http://doc.qt.io/qt-4.8/qlabel.html#margin-prop):
Doing:

```
mLabel->setMargin(42);
```

Should solve your problem.

However, if you surpass the size of half `QLabel` width (160 pixels in this example of 320 width `QLabel`), the `QPixmap` image won't show. In this case it is necessary to change the alignment property to **Right** doing next:

```
mLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeading|Qt::AlignRight|Qt::AlignVCenter);
```

In case that you need to set a *margin* that is above of the half of the size of QLabel, you'll need to calculate the margin doing next:

```
width_of_label - desiredmargin + width_of_image;
```

Which in this example of a 320 width `QLabel` and a 20 pixels width image) is next (using 220 as desired *margin*):

```
320 - 220 - 20 = 80;
```

So after setting the previous allignment, you should use:

```
mLabel->setMargin(80);
```

Comment: No, I had already tried `setMargin()` it is not working. My label is 320 pixels Wide. But If i give a margin of 220 pixels it is not showing image. Although for small values(like 42) it is showing image with some indentation.

Comment: What's the size of image?

Comment: 20x20 pixels dimensions

Comment: That's because if you are over half the size of the Label, (in this case 160 pixels). You need to change the alignment to display the image.
If you want to set margin of 220 -> you'll need to do `mLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignRight)`; and `mLabel->setMargin(80);` which is `width_of_ label - 220 + width_of_image`. In this case is `320-220+20=80`, tested and compared with a textLabel width a **indent** of 220.

Comment: Thank you for your response. Now i am trying to display image after 42 pixels by using `mLabel->setAlignment(Qt::AlignLeft);` and after that using `mLabel->setPixmap(pixmap);` But now it is not showing image even for a margin of 42.

Comment: Don't know what's happening to your code. I show you my [example](http://i.imgur.com/NMi1kM9.png). Left column with `AlignLeft` and right column with `AlignRight` respectively. The 20x20 sized images are in Labels of 320x320 size.

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/134248/discussion-between-jgorosdev-and-ramandeep-punia).